# What are the legal chars allowed in sql varchar?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to store a string in my table. The string will contain several substrings with a delimiter, the char ",".

Does varchar fit?

Comment: Certainly. Any printable ascii character will do (others too, but then it quickly becomes more technical).

Comment: If the delimiter is for storing several values, I strongly recommend not to do it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: And don't store opt/val lists like URL params, or string arrays in a varchar field. Store them in a table. |--ID--|--opt--|--val--|

Comment: Storing those in a table would be, in a way, a waste. I'm not going to query these values. Are you positive? @Just Aguy

Comment: You can store whatever you desire...just identifying some scenarios that aren't recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, VARCHAR is the preferred datatype to store strings.

Storing multiple values in the same field is not preferred, however. A multivalued attribute is usually implemented as a table in the database design.

Comment: So varchar can store chars like comma? And - if you say that storing multiple values in the same field is no recommended, what is your alternative, if a seperate table for these substrings I want to store is not necessary? @Emil Vikström

Comment: Yes, a VARCHAR field can store all characters. You say that a new table is "not necessary", but then you have already disqualified the correct, normalised way to design your database. Storing mutiple values in the same field breaks the first normal form (1NF) of relational database design. The result is that it is hard to search the table based on this attribute, indexes cannot be used, you cannot store commas in the attribute because comma is now a magic constant, JOINs against this attribute is almost impossible, slpitting the string may be awkward in some programming languages and so on.

Answer (score 1):

VARCHAR will work for you. But it does not mean that this is the right way to do it.

You should consider creating schema that stores each sub-string in separate row or column. This way data will be easier to read, write and, most importantly, search.